# Flipping the time axis and applying TimeDistributed RNN for preserving the spatial dimension

Tags: keras

The input shape of my Keras model is `(batch_size, time_steps, spatial_dim, features)`, which was fed through a TimeDistributed 1D convolution with N filters. The output of the TimeDistributed convolution is `(batch_size, time_steps, spatial_dim, N)`. I wanted to feed this output to an RNN, however, I did not want to lose the spatial_dim by flattening the last two dimensions. So I reshaped my convolution output as `(batch_size, spatial_dim, time_steps, N)` as an input to a TimeDistributed RNN layer. Is this valid to flip the time axis and apply TimeDistributed RNN for preserving the spatial dimension? Any other alternative to preserve the spatial_dim while applying RNN?

Comment: I do not think it is valid that your batch dimension are timesteps.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the conceptual mistake. I changed my model structure and updated my question accordingly.